# Jasmine Test Error : Expected Spy XYZ to have been called

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a method in component.ts file, which is calling a service method.
The code structure is like as following-

```
getDetails(){
  if(!alreadyCached){
     callLogFunction();
  }
  this.service.getData()
  .then(res => {
    //rest of the logic here
  })
  .catch(err=>{ //catch logic here })
}
```

My test block looks like this-

```
it('should call service.getData', ()=>{
  spyOn(service,'getData').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve([]);
  component.getDetails();
  fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
    expect(service.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }
}
```

Why am I getting error that **expected spy getData to have been called**
It would be great if you can help me with testing then and catch block (how to write tests for them)

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to test that `service.getData` is called, as per your test name, you should write the test thus:

```
it('should call service.getData', ()=>{

  const getDataSpy = spyOn(service,'getData');

  component.getDetails();

  expect(getDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  
}
```

That way you have tested only that which you want to test, that the service method is called, without having other distractions

Comment: Still same issue.Expected spy 'getData' to have been called

Comment: If you are still getting that error, try debugging your code. It literally means that the test is expecting that function to be called. Try logging in the different code segments and seeing where it fails